# What conditions must be satisfied to prove that a function is non-negative?

Tags: probability

I am currently trying to prove that some functions are probability density functions, satisfying the conditions that integrating across their domain is equal to 1, and that they are non-negative across this domain.

What conditions can I apply to show that these are non-negative? I was considering the following restrictions:

- Take the limits at each bound
- Show that the function is monotonically increasing or decreasing

Is this sufficiently robust, or is there a more complete form?

Answer (score 2):

The proof technique would heavily depend on the information you are given a priori about the function you want to prove is non-negative. You may have an explicit formula for your function, or you may only know that it is a solution of a very ugly differential equation.

That being said, my basic list of attempts for a function $f(x)$ would be:

1-Find a minimum for $f(x)$, then see that it is either zero or larger than zero.

2-Show that limits at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are zero.

3-Show that for any $\varepsilon>0$, $f(x)>-\varepsilon$

4-Show that for any $k<0$, $f^{-1}(k)\notin \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the domain of your variable.

Showing that the function is monotonic on any interval is not a necessary condition, since I could have $(1-\sin(x))e^{-x^2}$, and this is always nonnegative but not monotone on any interval larger than $2\pi$, and is a candidate for probability density function (up to normalization though).

Note that it is also necessary that :

$$
0<\int_\Omega f(x)dx =C<\infty
$$
In order for $f(x)$ to be a probability density function (though not necessarily normalized, unless you require $C=1$).

Answer (score 1):

Your title implies that you're looking for a necessary condition, but your question seems to be looking for sufficient conditions. Any one of the following is sufficient to prove that f is nonnegative over [a,b]:

1. f(a)>=0 and f is nondecreasing
2. f(b)>=0 and f is nonincreasing
3. f is continuous and has no roots in [a,b]
4. There is a nonnegative function g such that f is never less than g.
5. For all x in [a,b], either f'(x) exists and is equal to a nonzero number, or f(x)>=0 (so if f'(x) exists over all of [a,b], this reduces to proving that for all points where the derivative is zero, the function is nonnegative).

Comment: For the fifth condition wouldn't we required that $f'(x) > 0$ (or if $f(x)' = 0$ then $f(x) \geq 0$)? Otherwise any line with a negative slope would have $f'(x)$ non-zero, but that function is clearly not non-negative.